# How to enumerate all enabled roles for all users in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

If you want to check the roles that a user has access to, there is no easy way in PostgreSQL. In the `information_schema` there are relations `enabled_roles` and `applicable roles` but these only provide the privileges of the `current_user`. So how can I access the same information for *any* user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to make a recursive query over the system catalog relations `pg_roles` and `pg_auth_members`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE membership_tree(grpid, userid) AS (
    -- Get all roles and list them as their own group as well
    SELECT pg_roles.oid, pg_roles.oid
    FROM pg_roles
  UNION ALL
    -- Now add all group membership
    SELECT m_1.roleid, t_1.userid
    FROM pg_auth_members m_1, membership_tree t_1
    WHERE m_1.member = t_1.grpid
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.userid, r.rolname AS usrname, t.grpid, m.rolname AS grpname
FROM membership_tree t, pg_roles r, pg_roles m
WHERE t.grpid = m.oid AND t.userid = r.oid
ORDER BY r.rolname, m.rolname;
```

This gives a view of all users in the system with all inherited role memberships. Wrap this in a view to have this utility always handy.

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful as I was looking for just this sort of information. Adapting the work above to include a level to keep track of the inheritance

```
WITH RECURSIVE membership_tree(grpid, userid, lvl) AS (
-- Get all roles and list them as their own group as well
SELECT 
    pg_roles.oid
    , pg_roles.oid
    , 0
FROM
    pg_roles

UNION ALL

-- Now add all group membership
SELECT 
    m_1.roleid
    , t_1.userid
    , lvl + 1
FROM
    pg_auth_members m_1
INNER JOIN
    membership_tree t_1 
ON
    m_1.member = t_1.grpid
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.userid
    , r.rolname AS usrname
    , t.grpid
    , m.rolname AS grpname
    , t.lvl
FROM
    membership_tree t
INNER JOIN
    pg_roles r
ON
    t.userid = r.oid
INNER JOIN
    pg_roles m
ON
    t.grpid = m.oid
ORDER BY
    r.rolname
    , t.lvl
    , m.rolname;
```