# How to do "\dp" by query on postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find the information about how to do "Show Grants" on Postgresql. So far, the \dp command in psql is the most close result for me.

I searched the PG document and it didn't say any detail about where the \dp command gets information, or which table/view would contains them.

My question: What is the SQL statement could do the same thing like \dp in psql(or same thing like "Show Grants" in Mysql)?

BTW, I don't know if the table/view name that contains the info I wanted would be different between PG8 or PG9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the SQL run by `psql` for any backslash command by running `psql` with `-E`.

e.g.

```
$ psql -E
myuser=> \dp
```

**However**, `psql`'s queries aren't guaranteed to be cross-version portable. It may emit different queries for different PostgreSQL versions. If at all possible you should prefer to use [the `information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html)  instead.

Also, note that "Pg 8" or "Pg 9" is nonsensical, like saying "Windows 6.x". The "x" is very important. 9.1 and 9.4 are *very* different releases.

In this case I think you probably want [`information_schema.table_privileges`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-table-privileges.html) and [`information_schema.column_privileges`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-column-privileges.html).

Comment: This do helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

MySQL `SHOW GRANTS` shows all the privileges assigned to a specific user. PostgreSQL does not have a similar command; see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22315030/3304426) for a discussion. Using the pointers there it is not very difficult to piece together a query that returns results similar to what MySQL shows.

### User privilege, inherited privileges

Finding the privileges for an individual user is relatively straightforward using the `pg_roles` catalog table. But a user can also inherit privileges from other roles, possibly multiple levels deep. Analyzing that is - again - not available out-of-the-box. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22319589/3304426) shows you how you can list privileges granted to the user and privileges inherited through role membership.

### SHOW GRANTS

The below query will give you details on every privilege granted on tables and views, using the query from above (`priv_membership` view):

```
WITH rel AS (
  SELECT pg_class.oid,
         pg_class.relnamespace,
         pg_class.relname,
         (aclexplode(pg_class.relacl)).grantor AS grantor,
         (aclexplode(pg_class.relacl)).grantee AS grantee,
         (aclexplode(pg_class.relacl)).privilege_type AS privilege_type,
         (aclexplode(pg_class.relacl)).is_grantable AS is_grantable
  FROM pg_class
  WHERE pg_class.relkind::text = ANY (ARRAY['r'::text, 'v'::text]))
SELECT rel.oid AS reloid,
    mem.usrname AS rolname,
    rel.privilege_type AS privilege,
    sch.nspname AS schema,
    rel.relname,
    r1.rolname AS grantee,
    r2.rolname AS grantor
FROM priv_membership mem
JOIN rel ON rel.grantee = mem.grpid
JOIN pg_roles r1 ON r1.oid = rel.grantee
JOIN pg_roles r2 ON r2.oid = rel.grantor
JOIN pg_namespace sch ON sch.oid = rel.relnamespace
WHERE mem.usrname <> 'postgres'
  AND mem.canlogin IS TRUE
ORDER BY sch.nspname, rel.relname, mem.usrname;
```

This shows individual privileges so a single table or view may appear multiple times for a specific user. You can wrap this in a view for handy access and then easily filter on a specific user, schema, relation, etc.